# Direct ping to a server not working, but via another server?

Tags: ping, gateway

Have a small question..

I got below two ips from my team-mate...

G/W Details: 172.27.180.201    (abc/xyz)

Server Details:  192.168.40.132   (abc/xyz).

When I ping to 201, it goes fine. But ping to 132 didnt work.

Now if I do ssh to 201 and from there I ping to 132, then ping works fine.

So I am thinking what kind of changes I have to do in my Linux-machine(Any static route ??), so that I can directly ping to 132 machine ?

Please help me and let me know if I need to provide any other output details...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 machines (**G/W** & **Server**) are in different networks since they are using different private IP address ranges.

Private IP address ranges are as follows:

- Class A network `192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255` (65,536 IP addresses)
- Class B network `172.16.0.0  - 172.31.255.255` (1,048,576 IP addresses)
- Class C network `10.0.0.0    - 10.255.255.255` (16,777,216 IP addresses)

Since you can ping **G/W**:

- you are either in the same network and have a class B IP address
- you are in a different network which has access to **G/W**'s network by some means (gateway, vpn tunnel etc.)

**G/W** can ping Server because it has access to **Server**'s network (or **Server** itself) by some means (gateway, vpn tunnel, firewall etc.)

*Disclaimer: I'm not a network expert, my jargon maybe not appropriate* :)

Answer (score 0):

172.27.180.201 should do NAT for you.
Or 192.168.40.132 add route.
You can't access 192.168.40.132 only changing your host.